# Searching the last character of a string for punctuation

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm currently working on making a little word processor and I've come across an issue. I'm trying to make the program so that when you press enter, the program will put a full stop on your input and then a space (I'll sort out paragraphs later). The issue is that I can't get the program to search the last character for punctuation and then branch on the result. The compiler gives me the following error: **ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer.** The code I currently have is:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <limits>
using namespace std ;

int main() 
{
int i = 0;
string text ;
string text2 ;
string title ;
string usertitle ;
string filelocation = "C:/Users/" ;
string user ;
string punctuation = ". : ! ? "

cout << "Input a title for your file: " ;
getline(cin , title) ;
title.insert(title.length() , ".txt" ) ;
cout << "Your title is: " << title << endl ;
cout << endl << "Input the username associated with your computer: " ;
getline(cin , user) ;
filelocation.append( user ) ;
filelocation.append("/Documents/") ;
filelocation.append(title) ;
cout << "Your chosen file name and location is: " << filelocation << endl ;
for ( i = 1 ; i > 0 ; i++ )
{
    if (text == "") 
    {
        cout << "There are a few instructions that you need to follow in order to use this system effectively: " << endl ;
        cout << "The first being that if you want to use it, you actually have to use a directory that exists. " << endl ;
        cout << "The second being that when you want to exit the program you press enter with nothing typed" << endl ;
        cout << "The third being NOT TO USE FULL STOPS, THE PROGRAM WILL PUT THEM IN FOR YOU" << endl ;
        cout << "Please begin writing: " << endl ;
        getline(cin,text) ;
    } 
    if (text!="")
    {
        text2.append(text) ; //<===HERE IS WHERE I AM HAVING TROUBLE
        if ((text.at(text.size() -1 ) != "!" ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != "?") && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != ":" )) 
        {
            text2.append(". ") ;
            getline(cin, text) ;
        }
        else
        {
            getline(cin, text) ;
        }
        if (text == "") 
        {
            cout << "End of session" << endl ; break ;
        }
    }
}

ofstream writer( filelocation.c_str() ) ;
if(! writer) 
{
    cout << "Error opening file for output: " << strerror(errno) << endl ;
    return -1 ;
}
else 
{
    writer << text2 << endl ;
    writer.close() ;
}

return 0 ;
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You **always** need to check after reading if the read operation was successful. Also, testing if a `std::string` is empty is better done using `text.empty()`. The last element of a `std::string` is readily available using `text.back()`. Note, however, that the elements of a `std::string` are of type `char`, not of type `std::string`, i.e., you can't compare them against string literals (nor do you want to). Character literals look like `'?'`, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"!"` is a string, you want to compare against a character: `'!'`.

Comment: I actually tried this, but it kept going messed up after the first line that I put in and it said that the program stopped working. As if by magic it's now fine! Thank you for your "help" :P

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare `"!"` and `'!'`.

I suggest using `rbegin()` to address the last character:

```
        text2.append(text.begin(), text.end());
        switch(*text.rbegin())
        {
            case '!': 
            case '?': 
            case ':': text2.append(". "); break;
        }
        getline(cin, text);

        if(text.empty())
        {
            cout << "End of session" << endl;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((text.at(text.size() -1 ) != "!" ) && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != "?") && (text.at(text.size() -1 ) != ":" ))
```

That is both inefficient and is not doing what you think.  `text.at(text.size() -1 )` returns the last character.  To get what you want:

```
char lastChar = text[text.size() - 1]; // or char lastChar = *text.rbegin();
if (!(lastChar == '.' || lastChar == '?' || lastChar == '!')) // note the single quotes
{
    text2.append(".  ");        
}

getline(cin, text);
```

Comment: Yeah I wanted to compare the last character so that I could see if it is punctuation that doesn't need the program to input a full stop after pressing return. Thanks a bunch for your answer but it turns out that I had it right all along and my computer just wasn't having any of it!

Comment: If you are comparing a `char` to a `char*` (as you are in the code you posted), then you do not have it right ...

Comment: Well I don't know about `char*` but I've tested the code in front of me and it works fine.